# NSJSONSerialization issues. Incorrect JSON object sent to api

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, nsjsonserialization

In my xcode project I'm sending a post request with json data to my api using the Unirest library:

```
  NSDictionary *jsonObj = @{@"access_token": accessToken};

  UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response = [[UNIRest postEntity:^(UNIBodyRequest* request) {
    [request setUrl:@"http://localhost:9000/auth/facebook/token"];
    [request setHeaders:headers];
    // Converting NSDictionary to JSON:
    [request setBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObj options:0 error:nil]];
  }] asJson];
```

The jsonObj is formatted correctly when inspected.

But on the server side I'm seeing this object:

```
  {
    '{"access_token":"12345678910"}': '' 
  }
```

When it should be:

```
    {
      "access_token":"12345678910"
    }
```

What is happening here?

Comment: You're sending a JSON string as the key in a JSON "object", obviously.  I'm not familiar with UNIRest, but I suspect it's doing a second JSON serialization.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is something to do with the `asJson` method on the `UNIHTTPJsonResponse`.

My guess is that it's taking the contents of the body etc... and then "converting" it to JSON.

So, when this is already JSON it is wrapping up again.

Comment: I've tried a post request without the library and the same thing happens.